# Find the set, where the series converges: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^3+1}(x-3)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to find the set, where the series converges: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n n}{n^3+1}(x-3)^n.$$
I have already found $r=1$ and the center is $3$. So the set is $(2,4)$. Now I have to check, whether the series
is converges for $x=2$ and $x=4$.
And I don't know how to check it for $x=2$.
I don't know how to check is this series convergent: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n n}{n^3+1}(-1)^n.$$
Please help me. I have been stuck here for 2 hours.

Comment: To guide you to how you might deal with this series...is there any way to simplify the expression further?

Comment: Well I think we can simplify it like that : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n*n*(-1)^n}{n^3+1}$

Comment: Oh, I know, I can simplify it like that: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^3+1}$ . Am I right?

Comment: @TheStudent21 Yes, you are...because $\;(-1)^n(-1)^n=(-1)^{2n}=1\;$

Comment: Formatting tip: don't use * as a multiplication symbol (concatenation is enough, or use \cdot if you need to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n}{n^3+1}} = 1$$
So the radius of convergence is $1$. So, the set required is *at least* $(3-1, 3+1) = (2,4)$. Now, we will check if it converges at the endpoints.

- At $x = 2$, the absolute value of the series is equivalent to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$, so it does converge.
- At $x = 4$, the series is an alternating series, so [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) says us it does converge.

The final answer is $[2,4]$.

Comment: Well, I have already done that what you had said. But I have problem with verifying for x=4 now.

Comment: @TheStudent21 At $x = 4$, it is an alternating series.

Comment: The series is actually absolutely convergent at both endpoints, being comparable (in absolute values) to $\sum{1\over n^2}$ at both $x=2$ and $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

For both $x=2,4$, we have that

$$|(2-3)^n|=|(-1)^n|=1\text{ and }|(4-3)^n|=|1^n|=1$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^3+n}(x-3)^n\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^3+n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+0}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

(this last sum converges by the p-test).Thus, the original sum converges absolutely at $x=2,4$.